# Where is the `tabBarComponent` option in React-Navigation version 5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm migrating a RN project version 4 to 5.

I was using the `tabBarComponent` option to replace tab bar component with a custom one. [Old docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html).

How to achieve the same in version 5, I can't find this option in the [new docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/bottom-tab-navigator.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the new API way to achieve a custom tab component:

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

function MyTabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;

        const isFocused = state.index === index;

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
          });

          if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };

        const onLongPress = () => {
          navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabLongPress',
            target: route.key,
          });
        };

        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            accessibilityRole="button"
            accessibilityStates={isFocused ? ['selected'] : []}
            accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
            testID={options.tabBarTestID}
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
          >
            <Text style={{ color: isFocused ? '#673ab7' : '#222' }}>
              {label}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

// ...

<Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
  {...}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

This link will surely help. 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/bottom-tab-navigator.html#tabbar

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Do you know where is the `unmountInactiveRoutes` option too?

Comment: Here, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/bottom-tab-navigator.html#unmountinactivescreens